# Processing Thymeleaf Elements

Tags: java

How to check if object org.thymeleaf.dom.Element is a html tag  or some other?

I cannot find information about API for org.thymeleaf.dom.Element.

Comment: Please give some insight as to what you have tried and what you actually want. Show us some code.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: I wrote below what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean ifContains(Element element) {
    return element.contains("<img>");
}
```

I need funcionality like above.